# Parse JSSDK deleting object by id

Tags: javascript, node.js, parse-platform

I am trying to delete an object in cloud code and I have this function in my controller.

```
<!--language:lang-js-->

exports.del = function(req, res) {
  var post = new Parse.Query(CCPost);
  var objectId = req.params.id;
  post.get(objectId, {
    success: function(myObj) {
      // The object was retrieved successfully.
      myObj.destroy({
        success: function() {
          response.success('record deleted successfully');
        },
        error: function(error) {
          response.error('record delete failed');
        }
      });
    },
    error: function(object, error) {
      // The object was not retrieved successfully.
      // error is a Parse.Error with an error code and description.
    }
  });
};
```

I am getting the following error.

`E2014-07-07T18:05:58.186Z] v69: Ran custom endpoint with:`

`Input: {"method"=>"DELETE", "url"=>"/admin/post/UHvT5Ov2NO", "headers"=>{"version"=>"HTTP/1.1", "host"=>"share.cakeclub.me", "user-agent"=>"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36", "content-length"=>"144", "accept"=>"*/*", "accept-encoding"=>"gzip,deflate,sdch", "accept-language"=>"es,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6", "cache-control"=>"no-cache", "content-type"=>"multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryvzJX2gV7ZoN1mh2W", "origin"=>"chrome-extension://fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm", "x-forwarded-proto"=>"http"}}`

`Result: success/error was not called`

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here, any help would be great.

**EDIT**

I have edited my code to this.

```
<!--language:lang-js-->

exports.del = function(req, res) {
  var obj = new Parse.Object("CCPost"); 
  obj.id = req.params.id; 

  obj.destroy({
    success: function() {
      response.success('record deleted successfully');
    },
    error: function(error) {
      response.error('record delete failed');
    }
  });
};
```

Does this look right?

Comment: looks like you aren't passing in 'id'... the object id is in the url, and you dont actually need to fetch an object to delete it.  Fill out the other error function, which is why success/error aren't being called.

Comment: Could you show an example of how?

Comment: var obj = new Parse.Object("myClassName"); obj.id = "whatevs"; obj.destroy().then(function(){console.log('success');});

Comment: Thanks, I will have to wait to try it as parse deploy has stopped working now

Comment: We're looking in to that now.

Comment: @Fosco I have updated my question is this right?

Comment: yes, but make sure req.params.id contains the value... if you're calling a custom endpoint, not a function, I don't think it has what you want.

Comment: The url being called is ```/admin/post/UHvT5Ov2NO``` and is a delete route ```app.del('/admin/post/:id', adminController.del);```

Comment: Looks okay.. give it a shot..

Comment: Post your "EDIT" section as an answer, you are allowed to (and encouraged to) answer your own questions.

Answer (score 3):

My Final code block for delete, thanks for the pointers!

```
app.get('/admin/post/:id', function(req, res) {
    if (Parse.User.current()) {
        var PFObject = new Parse.Object("CCPost"); 
        PFObject.id = req.params.id; 

        PFObject.destroy({
          success: function() {
            res.redirect('/admin');
          },
          error: function(error) {
            res.send(500 ,'record delete failed -- '+ error.status);
            console.log(error);
          }
        });
    } else {
        res.redirect('/admin/login');
    }
});
```

Comment: That's should be a DELETE HTTP request not a GET